Why won’t my drill bit go farther in my stud
I’m trying to mount a tv but I’m having a really hard time drilling into the stud. Im using a deWalt drill and a craftsman 3/16 drill bit. I went past the drywall but now it’s feeling like I’m making no progress. Any help is very appreciated!

You can make a 1/2-inch hole in the drywall to SEE what's behind it. You don't even need a drill, you can use a screwdriver.  This won't make the TV mount screw any less effective and if you see you must move it a little, the hole will remain hidden by the mount.  You can similarly make a 1/2 inch hole a few inches to the left or right and use a cheap borescope to see if you have wood or metal studs and if you are near wires.    If in fact the wall is solid you should be able to tell easily.  Plaster on masonry looks and feels different to drywall.

Good chance you are hitting a metal protection plate.  Those plates protect electric wires or plumbing pipes.  Both are bad to drill into.
Move up or down a few inches to miss it.
There is a slim chance you hit a nail/screw head in the stud. Move a bit.
Are you sure it is a wood stud wall?  Not block/cement/brick wall.
